# Washing Kohen's Hands

Tags: minhag, kohen-priest, netilat-yadayim-washing, birchas-kohanim, levites-leviyim

Following kedusha during mussaf on a day when there is birchas kohanim (duchening), the Leviyim and Kohanim assemble at the sink and a Levi washes each Kohen's hands.

What procedure of hand-washing do they use here? I.e., alternating three times, one time, two on each etc.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16266/759

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a Levi, I pour the water in a slow continuous stream into the middle of the sink, and allow the Kohen to follow his minhag of whether to alternate hands or move each hand in and out of the stream several times. I can report that different Kohanim do different things.

Comment: Andrew, Welcome to judaism.SE, and thanks for the benefit of your practical experience! I look forward to seeing you around.