# Does the Levi who washes the hands of the Kohanim have to be over bar mitzvah?

Tags: minor-katan-child, netilat-yadayim-washing, birchas-kohanim, levites-leviyim, bechor-firstborn

The Leviim wash the hands of the Kohanim when they go up to bless the people. If a Levi is not available a first born (to the mother) can wash (according to the Askenazi custom) instead, Orach Chaim 128 (6) [MB 22].

Questions:

1)  Does the Levi have to be over bar mitzvah?

2)  If over bar mitzvah is not required and there is a Levi over the age of chinuch and a first-born over bar mitzvah, who gets the job?

Related [Why do the Leviim wash the hands of the Kohanim when they go up to bless the people?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/why-do-the-leviim-wash-the-hands-of-the-kohanim-when-they-go-up-to-bless-the-peo)  and [Washing Kohen's Hands](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6937/washing-kohens-hands)

Comment: From my experience, (sorry, no source) an over-bar-mitzvah Kohen must have his hands washed by an over-bar-mitzvah Levi. An underage Levi either washes the the hands of an underage Kohen, or he holds onto the cup with an adult Levi to wash the hands of an adult Kohen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Sefer Keser Kehuna 10:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7891&st=&pgnum=80) a minor Levi may only wash together with the adult Levi the Kohain. This is based on the Mordechai in Megila Perek 3 #815.

Comment: I don't see that in the Mordechai.

Comment: כדאשכחן
בערכין י׳׳א גבי שיר של לוים שאין הקענים עולין למנין המשוררים ואין עולין לדוכן אלא בין רגלי
הלוים היו משוררים כדי להתחנך

Comment: I don't see the word 'washing' anywhere. In fact that line isn't talking about duchening at all. The Mordechai does learn from there that minor __Kohanim__ can duchen with other adult Kohanim, but he says nothing about washing their hands (probably because leviim didn't wash the Kohanim's hands in the days of the Mordechai).

Comment: Well the Keser Kehuna is basing his Pesak that a minor Levi may only wash together with an adult Levi based on the Mordechai. Look at the Keser Kehuna. Perhaps you disagree, however I think that it is an important part of the answer to show where he is basing his premise upon.